# How to obtain the real output from a C function?

Tags: c, testing, cunit

I am having difficulty getting the real output from a C function.  For example:

```
int max3(int a, int b, int c){
    if ((a>b)&&(a>c))
       return a;
    if ((b>c)&&(b>a))
       return b;
    return c;       
}
```

Can you give me an idea of how to specify the real output (e.g. tools, algorithms, etc.)?
In this above example, the real output is 6 (in case (a,b,c) = (1,2,6)).
Thank in advance very much.

Comment: Quite unclear what you call the "real" output. Please explain.

Comment: Isn't it working as intended (i.e. 6 is returned)?

Comment: If you want to know what the method outputs, **run it and then you'll know**.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : my tool accepts input (CUnit )written in C; and the tool is written in Java. To be specific, i have to find a way to analyse the CUnit so obtain the return value from a function in java environment.

Comment: Do you mean that you cannot retrieve from the error report the value actually computed by the function ? If true, a solution is to define your own `CU_ASSERT` macro in such a way that it not only checks the returned value, but also formats (`sprintf`) the value in a string buffer, then passes it to `CU_assertImplementation`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have probably written it, as it is simple, using the ternary operator:

```
int max3(int a, int b, int c){       
    if (a>b)
       return (a>c)?a:c;
    else 
       return (b>c)?b:c;
}
```

Comment: Much easier to read. +1

Comment: Or in a way that generalizes: if (b > a) a= b; if (c > a) a= c; if (d > a) a= d; ... return a;